# How to check for a specific value exist in the firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write a query to check if there is any "Pending" status on **mcustDeliveryStatus**. I want to check in **Order** node that is there any Pending status for mcustDeliveryStatus.

[image: Example of my node:]

I wrote the following query

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");
final Query query = mDatabase.OrderByChild("mcustDeliveryStatus").equalTo("Pending");

                  query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(VWelcome.this, "new order", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(VWelcome.this, ViewOrderRequest.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This query works fine but the problem is intent runs even when there is no Pending status in my Order node.  Anyone knows why?

Comment: Does the order node should have only one child ? If not then what is the purpose of using singleValueEventListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you annotate your `DataSnapshot` object with `@NonNull`, it means that you tell the compiler that your object cannot be `null`, so it will always return something. With other words, if there are no results, it will return an empty `DataSnapshot` object. To solve this, you should check how many children are inside that object using the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference orderRef = rootRef.child("Order");
Query query = orderRef.orderByChild("mcustDeliveryStatus").equalTo("Pending");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String mGasBand = ds.child("mGasBand").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, mGasBand);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No data!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```